# I made mistake - sudo chown /var/www/html/htaccess.txt www-data:www-data

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, chown

I made mistake when use Chown command.
I write

```
sudo chown /var/www/html/htaccess.txt www-data:www-data
```

insted of

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www/html/htaccess.txt
```

The answer was -

[image]

So - All my stuff from /var/www/html disappeared, and my site

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at www.a-r-c-h.net Port 80
```

Comment: PLEASE - HELP!! How can I return it back?

Comment: your 1st command cant have done anything... there is not a file "www-data:www-data" so nothing got changed... please add results from `ls -l` for `/var/www/html/` edit: looked at the image now :D see! it shows an error so that did -nothing-

Comment: `/var/www/html/htaccess.txt` isn't a valid user either (as the error message states).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2 commands ABOVE the one you quoted in the questions messed your system up.

These 2 fix permissions for directories and files:

```
sudo find /var/www/html -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;    
sudo find /var/www/html -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

---

Your

```
sudo chmod 644 /var/www/html
```

removed execute permissions for your directories.

Comment: Thaks!!!!! It helps me! :))

Comment: But why it works so, that that command change rights but not the owner?

Comment: these 2 only change permissions to the files; not the owner; not the group.

Comment: I got it! I thought the problem was in sudo chown, but it was in sudo chmod 644 for folder, but not the file, thats why all files in Html disappeared. I made mistake - should be 755 for folders and 644 for files!

Answer (score 2):

You need to reset the permissions on `/var/www/html` back to `0755`:

```
sudo chmod 755 /var/www/html
```

**Explanation:** the execute bit in file permissions (`x`) determines whether the contents of the directory can be enumerated. Turning this bit off (`0644`) will prevent the web server from being able to see what is in the directory.